# Guice: How to Inject an instance of the default implementation of an interface?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I have an interface which has both a default implementation and a client-specific implementation.

Interface:

```
@ImplementedBy(CoreServiceImpl.class)
interface CoreService {
  // Methods
}
```

Default implementation:

```
class CoreServiceImpl implements CoreService {
  // Methods
}
```

In my specific Guice Module, I use a different implementation:

Module:

```
...
bind(CoreService.class).to(ClientSpecificServiceImpl.class);
...
```

Implementation:

```
class ClientSpecificServiceImpl implements CoreService {
  // Methods
}
```

However, within this class I require an instance of the default implementation.

**How can I tell Guice to "inject an instance of the default implementation of this interface"?**

I could reference the *current* default implementation by type name, e.g.

```
class ClientSpecificServiceImpl implements CoreService {

  private final CoreServiceImpl coreServiceImpl;

  @Inject
  ClientSpecificServiceImpl(CoreServiceImpl coreServiceImpl) {
    this.coreServiceImpl = coreServiceImpl;
  }
}
```

.. but if the default implementation (the one inside `@ImplementedBy`) changed, I wouldn't pick up the change. Should this be done via reflection? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an injection annotation, if you want different implementations to be injected in different places. In other words, for the one client:

```
class ClientSpecificApp {
  private final CoreService coreService;

  @Inject
  ClientSpecificServiceImpl(@Named("clientName") CoreService coreService) {
    this.coreService = coreService;
  }
}
```

For everyone else:

```
class DefaultApp {
  private final CoreService coreService;

  @Inject
  DefaultApp(CoreService coreService) {
    this.coreService = coreService;
  }
}
```

Then, bind that that annotation in your Guice module:

```
protected void configure() {
    bind(CoreService.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("clientName") CoreService);
}
```

Then, all you have to do is change the binding in the module for the client specific version if it changes.

Further reading: [Binding Annotations](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/BindingAnnotations)

Comment: I would prefer using an actual annotation for the binding rather than Names.named("") to prevent name collisions in the global namespace and spelling-mistakes with strings.